# NullReferenceException when using Treeview and PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, treeview, nullreferenceexception, propertychanged

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` when updating a bound property in my view model. This only happens when I use the `TreeView` control in the view. If I replaced it with a list, the exception goes away.

This is where the debugger breaks in my code:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

About maybe 30 calls later, through many `PresentationFramework` and `WindowsBase` assemblies, the exception actually occurs here:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.EvaluateOldNewStates()
```

This is the `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}, Path=Groups}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource categoryTemplate}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
          SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
```

And if I use this `ListBox` instead, the problem goes away:

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationServers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApplicationServer}" Height="auto"/>
```

I'm not sure that this will help, but here is the property that gets updated:

```
public ObservableCollection<ApplicationServer> ApplicationServers
{
    get { return this._applicationServers; }
    private set
    {
        this._applicationServers = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.ApplicationServers);
    }
}
```

And here is the call to update that property:

```
this.ApplicationServers = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationServer>(ApplicationServerLogic.GetAll().ToList());
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this?
I don't know what's causing the issue, and I'm tempted to just use the `ListBox`.

Indeed, I pretty much have to use the `ListBox` at the moment.
How can I even troubleshoot this? Is it a bug in the `PresentationFramework` assembly, maybe?

Also, this is the code-behind of my view, showing the handling of the item changed event.

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{           
    ((ApplicationServerViewModel)DataContext).SelectedApplicationServer = e.NewValue as ApplicationServer;
}
```

### Edit

Someone asked for more code, so here it is:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding ApplicationServers}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DeploymentEnvironment"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<!-- Our leaf nodes (server names) -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="serverTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- Note: The Items path refers to the items in the 
     CollectionViewSource group (our servers).
     The Name path refers to the group name. -->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource serverTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why not just add the items to the collection versus changing out the collection instance via the setter? The collection changed event is going to raise accordingly on the `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: have you tried removing all BS code?  `SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"`. `this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.ApplicationServers);` to `new PCEA("ApplicationServers")`. what does `categoryTemplate` look like? MORE CODE PLZ

Comment: @Aaron: Your suggestion worked, and it appears that will allow me to continue to use the treeview. Thank you.

Comment: @jberger: What is BS? AND PCEA? I added the code you requested to my original question.

Comment: @BobHorn: PCEA is `PropertyChangedEventArgs`.  As for BS, well, I think the B stands for 'bull', but I could be wrong....

Comment: Luke: Thanks. Aaron: The reason I wasn't adding and removing individual items is because the typical use for this is refreshing the entire list from the DB. A coworker implemented an ObservableCollection class that I can use; it has an AddRange() and disables firing the change event for each add.

Comment: @Aaron: If you want to post your suggestion as the answer, I'll accept it. It's at least a good work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't answer the why in your case; one approach would be to add the items to the collection instance versus changing out the instance via the setter. Remove the exposed setter and simply add the items as needed which will raise the `CollectionChanged` event on the underlying collection which will provide you with what you are ultimately after.

```
        public ObservableCollection<ApplicationServer> ApplicationServers
        {
            get { return this._applicationServers; }
        }

        ApplicationServers.Add(...);
```

Answer (score -1):

*I understand that this question is old.*

---

In my case, I was extending a `TabControl`, adding new features to it. One of those features changed the `SelectedIndex` property.

If that property was changed multiple times in a row, I would get the same exception.

Also, for some reason, I had to set one of the tabs to `IsSelected = true` or else the app would crash upon opening the window, with a similar exception:

```
▬ Message - 
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
○ Type - 
    System.NullReferenceException
▲ Source - 
    PresentationFramework
▼ TargetSite - 
    Void EvaluateOldNewStates(System.Windows.MultiTrigger, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs, Int32, System.Windows.Style, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
♠ StackTrace - 
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.EvaluateOldNewStates(MultiTrigger multiTrigger, DependencyObject triggerContainer, DependencyProperty changedProperty, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs, Int32 sourceChildIndex, Style style, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, Boolean& oldState, Boolean& newState)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.OnTriggerSourcePropertyInvalidated(Style ownerStyle, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, DependencyObject container, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs, Boolean invalidateOnlyContainer, FrugalStructList`1& triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, FrugalMap& propertyTriggersWithActions, Int32 sourceChildIndex)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.CreateDeltaSelectionChange(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(ItemInfo info, Boolean assumeInItemsCollection)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedIndexChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TabControl.OnGeneratorStatusChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.SetStatus(GeneratorStatus value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Generator.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.GenerateChildren()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.EnsureGenerator()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.get_InternalChildren()
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.StackMeasureHelper(IStackMeasure measureElement, IStackMeasureScrollData scrollData, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at MyApp.App.App_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in C:\fakepath\App.xaml.cs:line 223
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

---

Since I was dealing with the `Style` (inside `Themes\Generic.xaml`) of that new control, I started removing parts of the that custom style until it started working again.

I was able to find the problematic code. I had two `MultiTrigger` with 2 and 3 `Condition` inside. Each `MultiTrigger` had `Enter/Exit Actions` with a `Storyboard` inside.

By replacing the `MultiTrigger` with `MultiDataTrigger` and the setting the `Condition` inside to use a `Binding` instead of accessing directly the property, it started working again.

From this:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="DisplayAccent" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

To this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DisplayAccent, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```